# Issue with config file while using Arabic text in android?

Tags: android, ant, build.xml

I am using ant tool for customizing variables. For that i have used 
property file and i am giving my variable's values in this file. when i 
am giving any value is English in property file and building by ant 
command then i am getting
auto generated config.java file that have the value of property file but 
if i have given value in Arabic language and building by ant command 
then Config.java file does holds some garbage value:

For Example:

in property file i am putting values like this:

```
config.language_label = رقم الموبايل

after building getting value like that:
public final static String LANGUAGE_LABEL = "Ø±Ù‚Ù… Ø§Ù„Ù…ÙˆØ¨Ø§ÙŠÙ„";
```

Thanking In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Please note:**

-Android 2.1 does not have Arabic font.

-Android 2.2 has Arabic font but does not show your word correctly.

-Android 3.x supports Arabic completely.

So first of all make sure which version you are using.If you are using 3.x

**How To Implement RTL and Arabic in Android App:**

Please see page number 25 having following heading: **Advanced: right to left support**

http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/io-2013/presentations/147%20-%20Android%20Apps%20for%20a%20Global%20Audience.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Java Properties files have to be encoded in [ISO 8859-1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

The Properties file in your question appears to encoded in UTF-8. You can use the JDK's [native2ascii tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/native2ascii.html) to convert the text from UTF-8 to ISO 8859-1.

Running native2ascii on the given Properties file results in the following:

```
config.language_label = \u00d8\u00b1\u00d9\u201a\u00d9\u2026 \u00d8\u00a7\u00d9\u201e\u00d9\u2026\u00d9\u02c6\u00d8\u00a8\u00d8\u00a7\u00d9\u0160\u00d9\u201e
```